# Silent installer for wix 3.5 with custom actions in c#\.NET

Tags: c#, wix, installation, silent

Is there any way I can put all the properties and values of my WIX 3.5 installer, like the user inputs in my custom dialogs , into one single file and pass it to my MSI installer for silent installation? 
Something like one would do with a response file with installshield with a properties file?
I made sure to have all my custom actions in installexecute sequence. All my custom actions are in c#/.NET

Answer (score 2):

You use the Windows Installer SDK tool ORCA (MSI database editor) to create a transform.  In the transform you define all your properties.

[Editing MSI files with Microsoft Orca](http://www.scriptingsimon.com/2010/08/editing-msi-files-with-microsoft-orca-2/)

Once you have created your transform you perform the silent installation like this:

```
msiexec /I foo.msi TRANSFORMS=foo.mst /qn /l*v install.log
```

Silent installations completely skip the UI sequence so you aren't recording user input like a response file. You are setting properties and fully skipping the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

As you probably know, all the UI actions are skipped during a silent installation => no dialogs => no place for user inputs.

There are methods, though. You'll have to set the properties as they would have been set by the UI.

- First, as an alternative, you could build your installer without any dialogs that take user inputs => same outcome  with silent and non-silent installations.
- Second, if the defaults are okay, then no properties need to be changed.
- In any case, you might get by with passing property values on the msiexec command line.
- If not, Christopher Painter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273236/2226988) concerning transforms gives the most general solution.